# Routing to static pages in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a Help system for a Rails App, that uses a static page controller.

```
def show
  if valid_page?
   render template: "help/#{params[:page]}" 
else
  render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found
end
```

with route
      get 'help:page' => 'help#show', :via => [:get]

The Help folder started to become overwhelming with all the static views for the application.
So I wanted to split the views into sub-folders with associated controller - so in the Help folder is now

```
---Welcome
    ----index.html.erb
    ----about.html.erb
    ----contact.html.erb
---Blog 
    ----index.html.erb
```

etc

Under the help folder there are two dozen or so sub folders each with 3-6 help files, without creating a route for each subfolder, is there an way to have a single smart route to reference controller(folder) and page.

```
get 'help:folder:page' => 'help#show', :via => [:get]

def show
  if valid_page?
    render template: "help/#{params[:folder]}/#{params[:page]}/"
  else
   render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with `get 'help/:folder/:page' => 'welcome#show'`?

Comment: Finally sorted it with route 
       get '*help/:page' => 'help#show'
and in help controller
       def show
       render params[:help] + '/' + params[:page], :layout => 'application'  
     end
and a call 
    <a href="/help/welcome/about">

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it should work:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :help, only: [:index, :show] #-> url.com/help/:id
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/help_controller.rb
class HelpController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @page = Help.find params[:id]
      #no need to rescue this, rails will automatically throw a 404 error if not found
   end
end

#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type | title | body | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/models/help.rb
class Help < Page
end
```

The main issue you have is that you're storing each page as an `.html.erb` file. Whilst this will be okay in *certain* circumstances, in this case it's going to get very messy, very quickly.

You'll be much better creating a `Model` and `table` to store the `help` pages you need, allowing you to collate & invoke them as required. An added benefit to this will be that there will be no validation (Rails will handle it all), and you'll be able to use *one* view file to get it working:

```
#app/views/help/show.html.erb
<%= @page.title %>
<%= @page.body %>
```